# Python 3 PyQT (Using Designer), having issues starting

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt4, qt-designer

I am trying to branch out into developing a program with a GUI, and since I like KDE a lot I figured I would give PyQT a shot.  Here's an example of what I have so far (no logic just yet, I wanted to see if I could get the UI to display).

Here is the UI file named at.ui

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>410</width>
    <height>322</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <widget class="QTabWidget" name="tabWidget">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>0</x>
      <y>10</y>
      <width>261</width>
      <height>271</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="tabPosition">
     <enum>QTabWidget::North</enum>
    </property>
    <property name="tabShape">
     <enum>QTabWidget::Rounded</enum>
    </property>
    <property name="currentIndex">
     <number>2</number>
    </property>
    <property name="tabsClosable">
     <bool>false</bool>
    </property>
    <widget class="QWidget" name="tab">
     <attribute name="title">
      <string>Information</string>
     </attribute>
     <widget class="QWidget" name="formLayoutWidget">
      <property name="geometry">
       <rect>
        <x>0</x>
        <y>0</y>
        <width>251</width>
        <height>111</height>
       </rect>
      </property>
      <layout class="QFormLayout" name="formLayout">
       <item row="0" column="0">
        <widget class="QLabel" name="jobNameLabel">
         <property name="text">
          <string>Job Name</string>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item row="0" column="1">
        <widget class="QLineEdit" name="jobNameLineEdit"/>
       </item>
       <item row="1" column="0">
        <widget class="QLabel" name="inputDirectoryLabel">
         <property name="text">
          <string>Input Directory</string>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item row="1" column="1">
        <widget class="QLineEdit" name="inputDirectoryLineEdit"/>
       </item>
       <item row="2" column="0">
        <widget class="QLabel" name="albumNameLabel">
         <property name="text">
          <string>Album Name</string>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item row="2" column="1">
        <widget class="QLineEdit" name="albumNameLineEdit"/>
       </item>
       <item row="3" column="0">
        <widget class="QLabel" name="scalingAmountLabel">
         <property name="text">
          <string>Scaling Amount</string>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item row="3" column="1">
        <widget class="QComboBox" name="scalingAmountComboBox">
         <property name="sizePolicy">
          <sizepolicy hsizetype="MinimumExpanding" vsizetype="Fixed">
           <horstretch>0</horstretch>
           <verstretch>0</verstretch>
          </sizepolicy>
         </property>
         <item>
          <property name="text">
           <string>10% of Original</string>
          </property>
         </item>
         <item>
          <property name="text">
           <string>20% of Original</string>
          </property>
         </item>
         <item>
          <property name="text">
           <string>30% of Original</string>
          </property>
         </item>
         <item>
          <property name="text">
           <string>40% of Original</string>
          </property>
         </item>
         <item>
          <property name="text">
           <string>50% of Original</string>
          </property>
         </item>
         <item>
          <property name="text">
           <string>60% of Original</string>
          </property>
         </item>
         <item>
          <property name="text">
           <string>70% of Original</string>
          </property>
         </item>
         <item>
          <property name="text">
           <string>80% of Original</string>
          </property>
         </item>
         <item>
          <property name="text">
           <string>90% of Original</string>
          </property>
         </item>
         <item>
          <property name="text">
           <string>100% of Original</string>
          </property>
         </item>
        </widget>
       </item>
      </layout>
     </widget>
     <widget class="QTextEdit" name="textEdit">
      <property name="geometry">
       <rect>
        <x>3</x>
        <y>130</y>
        <width>251</width>
        <height>111</height>
       </rect>
      </property>
     </widget>
     <widget class="QLabel" name="label_3">
      <property name="geometry">
       <rect>
        <x>10</x>
        <y>110</y>
        <width>53</width>
        <height>14</height>
       </rect>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
       <string>Notes</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </widget>
    <widget class="QWidget" name="tab_2">
     <attribute name="title">
      <string>Manual</string>
     </attribute>
     <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_5">
      <property name="geometry">
       <rect>
        <x>30</x>
        <y>120</y>
        <width>181</width>
        <height>25</height>
       </rect>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
       <string>Step 1 (Copy Images)</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
     <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_4">
      <property name="geometry">
       <rect>
        <x>30</x>
        <y>150</y>
        <width>181</width>
        <height>25</height>
       </rect>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
       <string>Step 2 (Resize Images)</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
     <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_3">
      <property name="geometry">
       <rect>
        <x>30</x>
        <y>180</y>
        <width>181</width>
        <height>25</height>
       </rect>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
       <string>Step 3 (Upload Images)</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
     <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_2">
      <property name="geometry">
       <rect>
        <x>30</x>
        <y>210</y>
        <width>181</width>
        <height>25</height>
       </rect>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
       <string>Step 4 (Manage Album)</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
     <widget class="QLabel" name="label_2">
      <property name="geometry">
       <rect>
        <x>10</x>
        <y>10</y>
        <width>241</width>
        <height>61</height>
       </rect>
      </property>
      <property name="frameShape">
       <enum>QFrame::NoFrame</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
       <string>This is the manual method of uploading your images.  Complete all four steps and you'll be done!</string>
      </property>
      <property name="wordWrap">
       <bool>true</bool>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </widget>
    <widget class="QWidget" name="tab_3">
     <attribute name="title">
      <string>Automatic</string>
     </attribute>
     <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_6">
      <property name="geometry">
       <rect>
        <x>10</x>
        <y>170</y>
        <width>231</width>
        <height>61</height>
       </rect>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
       <string>Express Mode</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
     <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
      <property name="geometry">
       <rect>
        <x>10</x>
        <y>10</y>
        <width>241</width>
        <height>61</height>
       </rect>
      </property>
      <property name="frameShape">
       <enum>QFrame::NoFrame</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
       <string>This is the automatic method of uploading your images.  Clicking the 'Express Mode' button will finish the entire process for you.</string>
      </property>
      <property name="wordWrap">
       <bool>true</bool>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </widget>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>270</x>
      <y>250</y>
      <width>131</width>
      <height>25</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Exit</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QLabel" name="label_4">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>270</x>
      <y>0</y>
      <width>131</width>
      <height>81</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>First, fill out the fields in the Information tab.  Next, choose either Manual or Automatic processing.</string>
    </property>
    <property name="wordWrap">
     <bool>true</bool>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QLabel" name="label_5">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>270</x>
      <y>80</y>
      <width>131</width>
      <height>101</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>There are additional tools and options available in the menubar.  If you need any assistance, check out the Help menu for more information!</string>
    </property>
    <property name="wordWrap">
     <bool>true</bool>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_7">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>270</x>
      <y>220</y>
      <width>131</width>
      <height>25</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Export</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_8">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>270</x>
      <y>190</y>
      <width>131</width>
      <height>25</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Import</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>410</width>
     <height>21</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <widget class="QMenu" name="menuFileFile">
    <property name="title">
     <string>File</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QMenu" name="menuTools">
    <property name="title">
     <string>Tools</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QMenu" name="menuHelp">
    <property name="title">
     <string>Help</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <addaction name="menuFileFile"/>
   <addaction name="menuTools"/>
   <addaction name="menuHelp"/>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

I used pyuic to compile it into Python code and got the following, named at_auto.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'QT/at.ui'
#
# Created: Thu Feb  9 14:05:42 2012
#      by: PyQt4 UI code generator 4.9
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    _fromUtf8 = lambda s: s

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
        MainWindow.resize(410, 322)
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralwidget"))
        self.tabWidget = QtGui.QTabWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tabWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 10, 261, 271))
        self.tabWidget.setTabPosition(QtGui.QTabWidget.North)
        self.tabWidget.setTabShape(QtGui.QTabWidget.Rounded)
        self.tabWidget.setTabsClosable(False)
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("tabWidget"))
        self.tab = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.tab.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("tab"))
        self.formLayoutWidget = QtGui.QWidget(self.tab)
        self.formLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 251, 111))
        self.formLayoutWidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("formLayoutWidget"))
        self.formLayout = QtGui.QFormLayout(self.formLayoutWidget)
        self.formLayout.setMargin(0)
        self.formLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("formLayout"))
        self.jobNameLabel = QtGui.QLabel(self.formLayoutWidget)
        self.jobNameLabel.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("jobNameLabel"))
        self.formLayout.setWidget(0, QtGui.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.jobNameLabel)
        self.jobNameLineEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit(self.formLayoutWidget)
        self.jobNameLineEdit.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("jobNameLineEdit"))
        self.formLayout.setWidget(0, QtGui.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.jobNameLineEdit)
        self.inputDirectoryLabel = QtGui.QLabel(self.formLayoutWidget)
        self.inputDirectoryLabel.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("inputDirectoryLabel"))
        self.formLayout.setWidget(1, QtGui.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.inputDirectoryLabel)
        self.inputDirectoryLineEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit(self.formLayoutWidget)
        self.inputDirectoryLineEdit.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("inputDirectoryLineEdit"))
        self.formLayout.setWidget(1, QtGui.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.inputDirectoryLineEdit)
        self.albumNameLabel = QtGui.QLabel(self.formLayoutWidget)
        self.albumNameLabel.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("albumNameLabel"))
        self.formLayout.setWidget(2, QtGui.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.albumNameLabel)
        self.albumNameLineEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit(self.formLayoutWidget)
        self.albumNameLineEdit.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("albumNameLineEdit"))
        self.formLayout.setWidget(2, QtGui.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.albumNameLineEdit)
        self.scalingAmountLabel = QtGui.QLabel(self.formLayoutWidget)
        self.scalingAmountLabel.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("scalingAmountLabel"))
        self.formLayout.setWidget(3, QtGui.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.scalingAmountLabel)
        self.scalingAmountComboBox = QtGui.QComboBox(self.formLayoutWidget)
        sizePolicy = QtGui.QSizePolicy(QtGui.QSizePolicy.MinimumExpanding, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.scalingAmountComboBox.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.scalingAmountComboBox.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.scalingAmountComboBox.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("scalingAmountComboBox"))
        self.scalingAmountComboBox.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.scalingAmountComboBox.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.scalingAmountComboBox.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.scalingAmountComboBox.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.scalingAmountComboBox.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.scalingAmountComboBox.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.scalingAmountComboBox.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.scalingAmountComboBox.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.scalingAmountComboBox.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.scalingAmountComboBox.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.formLayout.setWidget(3, QtGui.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.scalingAmountComboBox)
        self.textEdit = QtGui.QTextEdit(self.tab)
        self.textEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(3, 130, 251, 111))
        self.textEdit.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("textEdit"))
        self.label_3 = QtGui.QLabel(self.tab)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 110, 53, 14))
        self.label_3.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_3"))
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab, _fromUtf8(""))
        self.tab_2 = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.tab_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("tab_2"))
        self.pushButton_5 = QtGui.QPushButton(self.tab_2)
        self.pushButton_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 120, 181, 25))
        self.pushButton_5.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton_5"))
        self.pushButton_4 = QtGui.QPushButton(self.tab_2)
        self.pushButton_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 150, 181, 25))
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton_4"))
        self.pushButton_3 = QtGui.QPushButton(self.tab_2)
        self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 180, 181, 25))
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton_3"))
        self.pushButton_2 = QtGui.QPushButton(self.tab_2)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 210, 181, 25))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton_2"))
        self.label_2 = QtGui.QLabel(self.tab_2)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 241, 61))
        self.label_2.setFrameShape(QtGui.QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.label_2.setWordWrap(True)
        self.label_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_2"))
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_2, _fromUtf8(""))
        self.tab_3 = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.tab_3.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("tab_3"))
        self.pushButton_6 = QtGui.QPushButton(self.tab_3)
        self.pushButton_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 170, 231, 61))
        self.pushButton_6.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton_6"))
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel(self.tab_3)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 241, 61))
        self.label.setFrameShape(QtGui.QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.label.setWordWrap(True)
        self.label.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label"))
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_3, _fromUtf8(""))
        self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(270, 250, 131, 25))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton"))
        self.label_4 = QtGui.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(270, 0, 131, 81))
        self.label_4.setWordWrap(True)
        self.label_4.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_4"))
        self.label_5 = QtGui.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(270, 80, 131, 101))
        self.label_5.setWordWrap(True)
        self.label_5.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_5"))
        self.pushButton_7 = QtGui.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(270, 220, 131, 25))
        self.pushButton_7.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton_7"))
        self.pushButton_8 = QtGui.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_8.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(270, 190, 131, 25))
        self.pushButton_8.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton_8"))
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtGui.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 410, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("menubar"))
        self.menuFileFile = QtGui.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuFileFile.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("menuFileFile"))
        self.menuTools = QtGui.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuTools.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("menuTools"))
        self.menuHelp = QtGui.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuHelp.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("menuHelp"))
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtGui.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("statusbar"))
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuFileFile.menuAction())
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuTools.menuAction())
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuHelp.menuAction())

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(2)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.jobNameLabel.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "Job Name", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.inputDirectoryLabel.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "Input Directory", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.albumNameLabel.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "Album Name", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.scalingAmountLabel.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "Scaling Amount", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.scalingAmountComboBox.setItemText(0, QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "10% of Original", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.scalingAmountComboBox.setItemText(1, QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "20% of Original", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.scalingAmountComboBox.setItemText(2, QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "30% of Original", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.scalingAmountComboBox.setItemText(3, QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "40% of Original", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.scalingAmountComboBox.setItemText(4, QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "50% of Original", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.scalingAmountComboBox.setItemText(5, QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "60% of Original", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.scalingAmountComboBox.setItemText(6, QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "70% of Original", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.scalingAmountComboBox.setItemText(7, QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "80% of Original", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.scalingAmountComboBox.setItemText(8, QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "90% of Original", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.scalingAmountComboBox.setItemText(9, QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "100% of Original", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.label_3.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "Notes", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab), QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "Information", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.pushButton_5.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "Step 1 (Copy Images)", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.pushButton_4.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "Step 2 (Resize Images)", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "Step 3 (Upload Images)", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "Step 4 (Manage Album)", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.label_2.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "This is the manual method of uploading your images.  Complete all four steps and you\'ll be done!", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_2), QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "Manual", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.pushButton_6.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "Express Mode", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.label.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "This is the automatic method of uploading your images.  Clicking the \'Express Mode\' button will finish the entire process for you.", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_3), QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "Automatic", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.pushButton.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "Exit", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.label_4.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "First, fill out the fields in the Information tab.  Next, choose either Manual or Automatic processing.", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.label_5.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "There are additional tools and options available in the menubar.  If you need any assistance, check out the Help menu for more information!", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.pushButton_7.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "Export", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.pushButton_8.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "Import", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.menuFileFile.setTitle(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "File", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.menuTools.setTitle(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "Tools", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.menuHelp.setTitle(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "Help", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
```

The Python script to start it is:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import at_auto, os

class at(at_auto):
    def __init__(self):
        at_auto.__init__(self)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    a = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    QtCore.QObject.connect(a, QtCore.SIGNAL('lastWindowClosed()'), a, QtCore.SLOT('quit()'))
    w = at(at_auto.__init__(self))
    a.setMainWindow(w)
    w.show()
    a.exec_loop()
```

When attempting to run the program, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./at.py", line 6, in <module>
    class at(at_auto):
TypeError: module.__init__() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)
```

I modified the code in at.py from the following tutorial:

http://wiki.python.org/moin/JonathanGardnerPyQtTutorial#Using_pyuic

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly: that tutorial you linked to is very out of date (it relates to PyQt3 rather than PyQt4), so I would suggest you have a look [here](http://www.diotavelli.net/PyQtWiki/Tutorials) for something more recent.

But to deal with the issue at hand - it will simplify things somewhat if you start by recompiling the ui using this command:

```
pyuic4 -w at.ui > at_auto.py
```

The `-w` option will generate an additional GUI class that is much more intuitive to use than the one created by default. The name of this class will have the same name as the top-level object created in Qt Designer - in your case, this will be `MainWindow`.

To use it, just import it into your `main` script, create a subclass, and then `show` an instance of it, like this:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
from at_auto import MainWindow

class Window(MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        MainWindow.__init__(self)
        # do other initialization stuff here...

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  That definitely got rid of the nasty error message.  Now I just have to figure out how to initialize the program correctly, as it seems to just start and finish.  Step in the right direction!  Well I added print statements to view what exactly is happening and now it opens the window correctly.  Strange.